# Informatica Cloud - Big Data Management

Tags: hadoop, informatica, informatica-cloud, bigdata

AFAIK Big data management in Informatica gives you an opportunity to run your mapping in distributed mode and it uses Blaze/Hive on MR/Hive on Tez/Spark as per the smart executor flow.

But only thing that I want to confirm, Is Big Data Management solution meant for Desktop Version only, Is it not something which is coupled with Informatica Cloud? Though only way through which you can distribute your task in Informatica Cloud is through nodes added under one secure agent group, I'm yet to identify how data is being split in secure agent group and what's the performance around it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, BDM was NOT available for the Cloud, but there is a scheduled webinar on April 18th, below is link for this,

https://now.informatica.com/reimagine-hybrid-data-management-scale-virtual-launch_agenda.html#fbid=X2w5n0TTrB0

Comment: Thanks, will keep any eye on it!